# How to make button disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this button:

```
<div class="ticket-edit-menu-el helper-float-left">
    <button class="btn btn-save" ng-click="submit()">
        <span class="btn-save-text">SAVE</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.editticketDescription($scope.getDescription());
    var validation = $scope.isTicketValid();
    if (validation == true) {
        ticketsService.postTicket($scope.ticket);
    } else {
        console.log(validation);
        $rootScope.$emit('newticketerror:' + validation);
    }
};
```

And on ng-click() my data saves to db, but button stay enabled and if i click again and again it's creating many copies of record in db. How I can disable my button when I click `save`?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HUSTLIN/fou9hbLs/1/)

Comment: could you give some more information please ?? when would you disable this button ?? on what conditions ? or maybe you want it disable all the time :) ?

Comment: When my data successfully saved to db, page will refresh, and so I need to make button disabled when I click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to use [**ng-disabled**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) in this case

```
<div class="ticket-edit-menu-el helper-float-left">
    <button class="btn btn-save" ng-disabled='isDisabled' ng-click="submit()">
        <span class="btn-save-text">SAVE</span>
    </button>
</div>

$scope.isDisabled=false;
$scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.isDisabled=true;
    $scope.editticketDescription($scope.getDescription());
    var validation = $scope.isTicketValid();
    if (validation == true) {
        ticketsService.postTicket($scope.ticket);
    } else {
        console.log(validation);
        $rootScope.$emit('newticketerror:' + validation);
    }
    //    $scope.isDisabled=false; when IO operation is done..
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-disabled` then add some conditions inside your `submit()` function.

**E.g.**

**HTML**

Add `ng-disabled="submitClicked"` in the `submit button`.

```
<div class="ticket-edit-menu-el helper-float-left">
    <button class="btn btn-save"
            ng-click="submit()"
            ng-disabled="submitClicked">
        <span class="btn-save-text">SAVE</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    if (!$scope.submitClicked) {
        $scope.submitClicked = true;
        $scope.editticketDescription($scope.getDescription());
        var validation = $scope.isTicketValid();
        if (validation == true) {
            ticketsService.postTicket($scope.ticket);
            $scope.submitClicked = false; // add this if the postTicket function failed to re-enable the button
        } else {
            console.log(validation);
            $rootScope.$emit('newticketerror:' + validation);
            $scope.submitClicked = false;
        }
    }
};
```

**Update:**

```
$scope.submitClicked = false; // use this code if ever the submission has failed or the server returns an error to re-enable the submit button and make it clickable again.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
 <div class="ticket-edit-menu-el helper-float-left">
  <button class="btn btn-save" ng-disabled='isDisabled' ng-click="submit()">
    <span class="btn-save-text">SAVE</span>
  </button>
 </div>

 $scope.isDisabled=false;
 $scope.submit = function () {
 $scope.isDisabled=true;
 $scope.editticketDescription($scope.getDescription());
 var validation = $scope.isTicketValid();
 if (validation == true) {
    ticketsService.postTicket($scope.ticket);
 } else {
    $rootScope.$emit('newticketerror:' + validation);
 }
};
```